# git recreate refs/heads/master after gc

Tags: git, git-commit, git-gc

after I run `git gc --prune=now` the file `.git/refs/heads/master` is deleted

how to recreate it? a remote application needs to read its text content (commit hash)

`.git/HEAD` content : `ref: refs/heads/master`

Comment: is `git pull` sufficient?

Comment: @ti7 this repo is used just to commit and push to another bare repo

Comment: Do not completely alter your question, especially after others have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git ls-remote <repo> refs/heads/master` is the solution, it works with both local and remote repositories

Comment: `git ls-remote` reads the commit of the master branch in the remote repository. The commit could be different from the master branch in the local repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay: I think that was the OPs goal (that is, the question was "how do I read the hash ID from a remote repository that happens to be, at the moment, readable via a mounted drive").

Answer (score 1):

If the file does not exist, you're not supposed to be using the file: the branch hash ID is now stored somewhere else.  Use `git rev-parse` or `git for-each-ref` to avoid depending on how the branch's value is stored.

If you have bad software you cannot fix, the trick to getting the branch file re-created is *currently* to make Git think that branch `master` has been modified.  To do that, make a commit and then un-make it, or use `git reset` to reset it to where it is; but remember that anything that works today might start failing tomorrow.  Someday there won't *be* any files here, so that case-sensitive branch names work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`git gc` packs refs and objects. Packed refs are stored in `.git/packed-refs`. There are many internal files under `.git`. Do not directly read these files. Use git commands instead, like `git rev-parse refs/heads/master` or `git for-each-ref refs/heads/master` or `git log -1 --pretty=%H refs/heads/master`.